# How we can add a new line in c#

Tags: c#, line, break, endl

**How we can write output on second line in c# ??**
How we can write the given code into two lines

```
MessageBox.Show("my name is " + LineBreak, "yazdan" ,
                 MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

How we can start a new line after "my name is " and before "yazdan"

Comment: Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
"my name is " + "\n" + "yazdan"
```

you can use either `"\n"` or `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
"my name is " + Environment.NewLine + "yazdan"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show("my name is " + Environment.NewLine + "yazdan", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your environment, in Unix it is just "\n", however in Windows environments you need "\r\n". These are both written as strings.

\r = Carriage return
\n = Line feed

This is the equivalent to vbCrLf in VB.NET

Comment: i'm using window